# User kubernetes persisted volumes with cockroachdb

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, nfs, rancher, cockroachdb

I am trying to locally deploy **cockroachdb** for use with Kubernetes on Rancher. I have created 3 Kubernetes persistent volumes with hostPath set as a local directory.

When I try to deploy cockroachdb through:

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/master/cloud/kubernetes/cockroachdb-statefulset.yaml
```

two of the three created pods show error.

The logs of one of the failed pods show this:

```
I180202 08:47:45.224556 39 storage/engine/rocksdb.go:411  opening rocksdb instance at "/cockroach/cockroach-data"
E180202 08:47:45.285297 1 cli/error.go:68  cockroach server exited with error: failed to create engines: could not open rocksdb instance: IO error: lock /cockroach/cockroach-data/LOCK: Resource temporarily unavailable
Error: cockroach server exited with error: failed to create engines: could not open rocksdb instance: IO error: lock /cockroach/cockroach-data/LOCK: Resource temporarily unavailable
Failed running "start"`.
```

The directory which is the hostPath of the 3 persistent volumes show this:

```
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 5 root        root        4096 Feb  2 12:59 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 user        user        4096 Feb  2 12:59 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root           0 Feb  2 12:59 000003.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root        root        4096 Feb  2 12:59 auxiliary
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root          57 Feb  2 12:59 cockroach.advertise-addr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root          13 Feb  2 12:59 COCKROACHDB_VERSION
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root          12 Feb  2 12:59 cockroach.http-addr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root          19 Feb  2 12:59 cockroach.listen-addr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root          16 Feb  2 12:59 CURRENT
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root          37 Feb  2 12:59 IDENTITY
drwxr-xr-x 3 root        root        4096 Feb  2 14:38 local
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root           0 Feb  2 12:59 LOCK
drwxr-xr-x 2 root        root        4096 Feb  2 14:38 logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root          13 Feb  2 12:59 MANIFEST-000001
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root        4241 Feb  2 12:59 OPTIONS-000005
```

I tried setting up nfs for rancher but the catalogs show that rancher-nfs is not compatible.

Comment: Are you using the same external hostPath for all three volumes? Multiple cockroach nodes cannot share the same data directory, they need separate directories. This is what the error is saying: another instance is already using that directory.

Comment: you didn't use host path

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marc. I had to manually create pv because I don't have access to any of the cloud providers and overlooked this small part. Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to create and attach the `datadir` persistent volume for cockroachdb. But it is not letting me. Can you share your steps @SwapnilPandey?

Comment: @PrashantPatel I solved the issue by creating three different pv. Maybe this can be of help to you.

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks.